# Why the need for InputStream in HTTP Clients? (Java)

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been using various HTTP clients in java for getting various pieces of information from websites or for using web services (like the google maps geocoder)

The current client I'm working with is the [HTTP Components client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from Apache.

What I always wonder is why there is no .getText() or .getBytes() method that simply gives me all the contents of the url, but instead there are methods that return InputStream. What is the point or the reason for that?

It's not like I continuously comunicate with the server so that I would have to keep checking the stream. HTTP is stateless, so why is there no getText()/getBytes() method that simply returns the contents of the HTTP response (as String or byte[]), after it was received?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the server starts outputting the result in a stream, and the client gets it that way. You can buffer that stream in memory and transform it to a `String` / `byte[]`, but you can also process parts of it, and discard them.

Comment: Yes, but by the time I get my response-object the data has been received and the connection has been closed - right?

Comment: Not really. HttpClient streams the data from the underlying connection which is kept open at least until the response entity body is fully consumed

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a network; because it's a stream; because the server response can be arbitrarily large. Same reasoning applies to files.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what's already mentioned, an input stream is mandatory for the following scenario: the HTTP server providing a 1 GB response to a client running in a JVM with -Xmx512M. `getBytes()` or `getString()` can only result in an `OutOfMemoryError`, while reading the input stream (1K at a time) makes perfect sense.

Comment: So the data isn't being read into the JVM's memory until I read it from the inputstream? I always assumed the client does it's http stuff and then closes the connection, regardless of what I do with the response.

Comment: This depends entirely on the client, but in the above scenario, a client that reads the whole response into memory will just crash. As far as I know, in HttpClient (HttpMethodBase, actually), it depends on the usage whether the response is read as byte array into memory or the input stream is returned for the client to read the data over the network.

Answer (score 1):

You have [EntityUtils.toString(entity)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29).